# Define a param in variable

Tags: perl

I am having trouble creating a string that defines a param within it, like this:

```
my $string = " my name is $q->param('name')";
```

When I print I get "my name is CGI=HASH(0x354680)->param('name')"

What am I doing wrong. I would like to avoid defining a variable before hand because I have a ton of params to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
my $string = " my name is ". $q->param('name');
```

To avoid the concatenation you could first load up the params into a hash:

```
my @names = qw(name email);
my %params = map { $_ => $q->param($_) } @names; 
my $string = " my name is $params{'name'}";
```

Be careful if some of your params have multiple values.

Comment: I thought this would be the case. Looks like Im gonna have a lot of concatenation

Comment: There are other solutions, maybe show some more of your code.

Comment: See my update for avoiding the concatenation

Comment: Why avoid concatenation just for the sake of avoiding concatenation? Using a hash requires *more* typing and the intent is not nearly as clear as just using the concatenation operator.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I take your point about intent, but if there is a 'ton' of params, and you called the hash say %p, then you would _save_ typing. Also, if the value of the param is used multiple times the hash would be more efficient, i.e. you would avoid multiple method calls.